# Spring MVC @RequestMapping produces

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm trying to understand what's going on behind the scenes when using the *produces* param of *@RequestMapping* (e.g. `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` )

I read somewhere that it calls MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter? But I can't see the connection and in the Spring Doc I couldn't find what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this document?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Find the "json" or "Jackson" text!

Comment: Yes, I read that particular part about produces. But I'm interested in knowing where the connection between the defined produced media type and the called converter class is.

Comment: if you want to know more, I think instead of reading document, you should read the spring mvc source code

Comment: Ok I found a Bean in our application that has a member variable `private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters;` I guess that Spring scans for _HttpMessageConvert_.

This also helped me understanding it a little bit better: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html